# Is it possible to reuse import code in Python?

Tags: python, import, python-import, code-reuse

There are several imports that are common between some files in my project. I would like to reuse this code, concentrating it in a unique file and have just one import in the other files. Is it possible?

Or is there another way not to replicate the desired import list in multiple files?

Comment: While that would be possible by writing a function that manipulates the namespace, it is common practice in Python to repeat the imports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its possible. You can create a Python file with imports and then import that Python file in your code.

For Eg:

**ImportFile.py**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
```

**MainCode.py:**

```
from ImportFile import *

#Here you can use pd,np,os and complete your code
```

OR

```
from ImportFile import pd,np

#And then use pd and np
```

Comment: You already posted an answer almost identical to this one, and then you deleted it for some reason. Trying to hide the criticism? It's still a bad idea. The `import *` version is still bad practice for the usual reasons `import *` is considered bad practice: it obscures what names you're importing and where they come from, and it can easily lead to name collision.

Comment: The second version is a bad idea because you could just do `import pd, np` without having `ImportFile` at all.

Comment: Additionally, concentrating all imports into a single module dramatically increases the risk of circular import bugs.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica why will I delete the old post? And whats the criticism in that answer? It was flagged by someone might be, I am not sure why it got deleted.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica And I just answered the question what user asked. User asked ```is it possible to have a unique file and have just one import in the other files```. And the answer is **Yes**. So that question I have answered

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica The second approach is used to avoid all imports in one file. And moreover user has mentioned that he wants an unique file for imports. So question of not having ```ImportFile``` doesn't arises.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Anything you need to add or ask now?

Comment: Considering that the goal was "not to replicate the desired import list in multiple files", your second approach (which requires replicating the imports in every file) doesn't seem useful. Also, I can *see* the banner on your previous post saying "This post is hidden. It was deleted 1 hour ago **by the post author**."

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica The user wants the separate file for imports. Right?
He doesn't want all the 100 imports to write in each and every file
So he wants a common file for that.
Writing 100 imports in all files and writing one importfile line in all file makes a huge difference.

Comment: `from ImportFile import pd, np` is not some kind of huge improvement over `import pd, np`. It's just worse.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Can you please read the question properly? The user wants one file for imports. And he asked us is it possible. I have answered to this question. Its the user requirements to have one file all imports.

Comment: The question asked for code reuse. Your second approach performs only code duplication. That's the opposite of the goal.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Read this properly: `` have just one import in the other files. Is it possible?``` 

Or is there another way not to replicate the desired import list in multiple files?```

Comment: It was useful. I can concentrate multiple lines imports (getting structures from different modules) in a unique file and `from` it just get what I want in a single line. Anyway thanks for the complementary evaluation, Monica!

Comment: I realized later that the NumPy and Pandas imports are using aliases, so the direct import would either be `import numpy, pandas` or `import numpy as np, pandas as pd` rather than `import np, pd`. If you have a ton of aliases you want to use, this does have the potential to reduce code duplication (so I withdraw my objection regarding that), but it comes at the price of obscuring what you're actually importing. (Is `sp` `scipy` or `sympy`? Is `random` the stdlib `random` or `numpy.random`? The issue gets more severe with more obscure modules and less standard aliases.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Sorry for any rude sentence if any... :-)

Comment: A good use case for such import is for interfacing directly (I have a requirement to send raw SQL queries rather than using some ORM) with different DB backend (that supports DBAPI) depending on some configuration. Import the correct backend as `db` with some logic then other part of the code can always use `db` to interface with the database.